# TFS Build email alerts to the [Requested By] user

Tags: build, alert

Is this possible? 
Me and one of my co-worker are looking for this kind of solution for a while now and we can't find anything similar on Google.

The thing is simple. We want to automatically alert the [Requested By] user by email when he or she break the build on TFS 2010. How can we do this, there must be a solution, Microsoft can't had forgotten one of the simplest feature that can be added...

Thanks for your answers. If you need more clarifications about my question, please ask!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this, but you have to customise the build process or use web services, I've done this by customising our build process. I used a list of users from `associatedChangesets` instead of requested by.

1. Get the [TFS Build Extenstions](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/).
2. Open your build process template (guides [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=494) and [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=498)).
3. Navigate to the "If a Compilation Exception Occurred" section.
4. Drag on the "Email" activity from the "TFS Build Extensions".
5. In the "To" field enter the following VB.Net:

**To:**

```
New String() { _
    DirectCast(
        New System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher( _
        String.Format("(&(objectClass=user)(|{0}))", BuildDetail.RequestedBy)) _
        .FindOne(), SearchResult) _
        .Properties("mail")(0).ToString() _
}
```

6: Complete the rest of the fields in the Email activity.

Comment: Thanks, this seams to be our solution. I'm still trying to figure out how I can use this piece of code correctly though.

Our Domain Controller needs authenticated binds, so I need to use a user account and password to obtain information on a user. As I can see, there's no such binds in the code you just gave me. I tried to reproduce the same thing under C#, but I can't... I don't find a similar way under C# to use DirectCast...

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: As I stated, this code was ported from a more complex solution so might not run. I found the bets way to get the Expression correct was to use Linqpad. I don't think you need the DirectCast in Normal C#, but it is needed in the VB Expression because Windows Workflow has "Option Strict On".

Answer (score 3):

Yes - you will be able to do this with the next version of Team Foundation Server. I have an example of it here on my blog post:  http://www.edsquared.com/2012/02/09/Creating+EMail+Alerts+For+Team+Members+In+TFS.aspx

[image]

Comment: Do we know the difference between "Requested For" and "Requested By"?

Answer (score 1):

You could install the [TFS power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) and use the [alerts explorer](http://www.edsquared.com/2010/02/25/Where+Is+The+Alerts+Editor+Explorer+In+The+TFS+2010+Power+Tools.aspx) to set up email alerts. It's not perfect as I think each Developer needs to set up their own alert but if it's just the 2 of you that shouldn't be a problem