# IBuildDetail TFS Service

Tags: tfsbuild

Does anyone know how to get the email address associated with requesting/triggering a build?
If I use the `IBuildDetail` object and look at the `RequestedBy` property, it gives me the display name instead of the live id.

Any ideas?

Comment: is the email address associated with the TFS account?

Comment: Yes it is associated with the display name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to search the Active Directory with the RequesteBy property and get the email address from the AD. 
You can use the [DirectorySearcher method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Also look at this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501751/tfs-build-email-alerts-to-the-requested-by-user)